# $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ then $ \|A^{-1}-B^{-1}\|\leq\|A^{-1}\|\|B^{-1}\|\|A-B\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reworking my lectures and in one proof our prof used the following:

Let $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$  invertible. Then $ \|A^{-1}-B^{-1}\|\leq\|A^{-1}\|\|B^{-1}\|\|A-B\|$

Unfortunately I have no clue how to show this, so how can you prove this?

Comment: you should probably specify that your norm has the multiplicative property.  There are many norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and not all of them do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $B^{-1}-A^{-1}=A^{-1}(A-B)B^{-1}$.